# Render dynamic templates in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember, so this might be a stupid question, but bear with me. Is there a specific reason one can't render templates with a dynamic string? Specifically, I push various objects to a controller variable like this:

```
this.controllerFor('application').get('popups').pushObject({
  resource: article,
  template: 'article'
});
```

And then try to render them:

```
{{#each popup in model}}
  {{ render popup.template popup.resource }}
{{/each}}
```

This doesn't work in Ember as-is, since it expects a string as the template. I just patched this in my ember source in the `renderHelper` function:

```
if(name.value) name = name.value();
```

This makes sure that if the name comes from a property, it gets converted to a string correctly. It works perfectly fine. What is the reason Ember doesn't support this out-of-the-box? Am I missing something?

A little background for the stuff above: I want to open lots of different resources in popups on the page, but I want to keep the popups separated from the rest of the current route so I can show them on their own page if needed without duplicating code. My idea was that I push all open popups to a global array, and they are rendered at the bottom of the page (A bit like we do it at the moment without ember). Maybe there is a better way to do this that I missed!

Answer (score 0):

You want to

- Create a popup template independent of route
- Pass data to template and render it any where

Right ? If yes there is a very good concept of `component` in Ember.js

Component is a small module with is separate from application. It only depends upon the data passed into it.

It can be reused in different portion without ever effecting each other. They are especially good to run third party plugins like qtip etc.

[here](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/) is good article about use case of component.

Comment: No, not exactly. I already thought about using a component, but it didn't really work out. My problem is that I need to render a template *inside* the popup, including the controller/route etc. But more specifically, this template needs to have a dynamic path, which is the real issue I tried to describe above. A component would make it reusable, but all popups are rendered in one single place anyways. I basically want to push templates into a popups array ;)

Comment: there is `templateName` property of the component which you can override. but I have never tried to do that.

Comment: Well, then the whole component has this template. I want some shared code inside the popup and the popup's contents should come from a template.